# gmail schema: rsvp action not validating

Tags: google-schemas

I'm assuming this has something to do with the validation tool being an early release.  The RSVP action isn't validating well.  The markup below also isn't showing in gmail, and I'm at a loss as to why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "schema.org",
  "@type": "Event",
  "name": "3pm April 21st",
  "startDate": "2013-05-05T15:00:00",
  "endDate": "2013-05-05T16:00:00",
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "name": "XXXX",
      "streetAddress": "999 West Adams",
      "addressLocality": "Chicago",
      "addressRegion": "IL",
      "postalCode": "60607",
      "addressCountry": "USA"
    }
  },
  "action": [
    {
      "@type": "RsvpAction",
      "handler": {
        "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
        "url": "http://foobar.net/1"
      },
      "attendance": "http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Yes"
    },
    {
      "@type": "RsvpAction",
      "handler": {
        "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
        "url": "http://foobar.net/2"
      },
      "attendance": "http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/No"
    },
    {
      "@type": "RsvpAction",
      "handler": {
        "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
        "url": "http://foobar.net/3"
      },
      "attendance": "http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Maybe"
    }
  ]
}
</script><img alt="Open_tracker" src="http://localhost:3000/invitations/14157/open_tracker"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
1
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
2
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
3
<head>
4
<script type="application/ld+json">
5
{
6
  "@context": "schema.org",
7
  "@type": "Event",
8
  "name": "3pm April 21st",
9
  "startDate": "2013-05-05T15:00:00",
10
  "endDate": "2013-05-05T16:00:00",
11
  "location": {
12
    "@type": "Place",
13
    "address": {
14
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
15
      "name": "XXX",
16
      "streetAddress": "999 West Adams",
17
      "addressLocality": "Chicago",
18
      "addressRegion": "IL",
19
      "postalCode": "60607",
20
      "addressCountry": "USA"
21
    }
22
  },
23
  "action": [
24
    {
25
      "@type": "RsvpAction",
26
      "handler": {
27
        "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
28
        "url": "http://foobar.net/1"
29
      },
30
      "attendance": "http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Yes"
31
    },
32
    {

Extracted structured data
Item1
Type: 
RsvpAction  
Unknown type RsvpAction
Properties:
   attendance 
http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/No 
Unknown property http://schema.org/attendance
The property attendance cannot be used with the RsvpAction type
   handler  
Item3 
Unknown property http://schema.org/handler
The property handler cannot be used with the RsvpAction type
Item2
Type: 
Place 
Properties:
   address  
Item9 
Item3
Type: 
HttpActionHandler 
Unknown type HttpActionHandler
Properties:
   url  
http://foobar.net/2  
Item4
Type: 
HttpActionHandler 
Unknown type HttpActionHandler
Properties:
   url  
http://foobar.net/3  
Item5
Type: 
HttpActionHandler 
Unknown type HttpActionHandler
Properties:
   url  
http://foobar.net/1  
Item6
Type: 
Event 
Properties:
   startDate  
2013-05-05T15:00:00 
Not a valid DateTime value
Not a valid Date value
   endDate  
2013-05-05T16:00:00 
Not a valid DateTime value
Not a valid Date value
   name 
3pm April 21st  
   location 
Item2 
   action 
Item8 
Item1 
Item7 
Item8 
Item1 
Item7 
Item8 
Item1 
Item7 
The property action cannot be used with the Event type
The property action cannot be used with the Event type
The property action cannot be used with the Event type
Item7
Type: 
RsvpAction  
Unknown type RsvpAction
Properties:
   attendance 
http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Maybe  
Unknown property http://schema.org/attendance
The property attendance cannot be used with the RsvpAction type
   handler  
Item4 
Unknown property http://schema.org/handler
The property handler cannot be used with the RsvpAction type
Item8
Type: 
RsvpAction  
Unknown type RsvpAction
Properties:
   attendance 
http://schema.org/RsvpAttendance/Yes  
Unknown property http://schema.org/attendance
The property attendance cannot be used with the RsvpAction type
   handler  
Item5 
Unknown property http://schema.org/handler
The property handler cannot be used with the RsvpAction type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validation tool in the docs is in alpha and it doesn't support all new types yet. Besides, RSVP and Review actions are not currently supported by Gmail, as reported in the reference guide: https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/rsvp-action

Comment: It also doesn't help that support is spread so thin - should we seek answers over at Google Calendar on the product forums? Google Email?  Or maybe one of the API product forums (of which one is shut down due to malware). Or here on stack overflow? Would crave some empirical answers on schema integration being posted somewhere, if only we knew where. SEO focused schema discussion seems to be burying the more functional ideas...